# python: how to apply callback function for multiprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In my GUI application, I want to use `multiprocessing` to accelerate the calculation. Now, I can use `multiprocessing`, and collect the calculated result. Now, I want the subprocess can inform the main-process that the calculation is finished, but I can not find any solution.

My `multiprocessing` looks like:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self,name, array):
        super(MyProcess,self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.array = array
        recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
        self.recv = recv_end
        self.send = send_end

    def run(self):

        s = 0
        for a in self.array:
            s += a
        self.send.send(s)

    def getResult(self):
        return self.recv.recv()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_list = []
    for i in range(5):
        a = np.random.random(10)
        print(i, ' correct result: ', a.sum())
        p = MyProcess(str(i), a)
        p.start()
        process_list.append(p)

    for p in process_list:
        p.join()

    for p in process_list:
        print(p.name, ' subprocess result: ', p.getResult())
```

I want the sub-process can inform the main-process that the calculation is finish so that I can show the result in my GUI.

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

Comment: Why not use a pool instead? Even if you were to pass a queue/pipe, you would need to empty those before joining otherwise it will deadlock. Better to just use a pool here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would like to do something with a result (the sum of an `numpy` array, in your case) as soon as it has been generated, then I would use a multiprocessing pool with method `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` with method `imap_unordered`, which will return results in the order generated. In this case you need to pass to your worker function the index of the array in the list of arrays to be processed along with the array itself and have it return back this index along with the array's sum since this is the only way for the main process to know for which array the sum has been generated:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np

def compute_sum(tpl):
    # unpack tuple:
    i, array = tpl
    s = 0
    for a in array:
        s += a
    return i, s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_list = [np.random.random(10) for _ in range(5)]
    n = len(array_list)
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), n)
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    # get result as soon as it has been returned:
    for i, s in pool.imap_unordered(compute_sum, zip(range(n), array_list)):
        print(f'correct result {i}: {array_list[i].sum()}, actual result: {s}')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
correct result 0: 4.760033809335711, actual result: 4.76003380933571
correct result 1: 5.486818812843256, actual result: 5.486818812843257
correct result 2: 5.400374562564179, actual result: 5.400374562564179
correct result 3: 4.079376706247242, actual result: 4.079376706247242
correct result 4: 4.20860716467263, actual result: 4.20860716467263
```

In the above run the actual results generated happened to be in the same order in which the tasks were submitted. To demonstrate that in general the results could be generated in arbitrary order based on how long it takes for the worker function to compute its result, we introduce some randomness to the processing time:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np

def compute_sum(tpl):
    import time

    # unpack tuple:
    i, array = tpl
    # results will be generated in random order:
    time.sleep(np.random.sample())
    s = 0
    for a in array:
        s += a
    return i, s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_list = [np.random.random(10) for _ in range(5)]
    n = len(array_list)
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), n)
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    # get result as soon as it has been returned:
    for i, s in pool.imap_unordered(compute_sum, zip(range(n), array_list)):
        print(f'correct result {i}: {array_list[i].sum()}, actual result: {s}')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
correct result 4: 6.662288433360379, actual result: 6.66228843336038
correct result 0: 3.352901187256162, actual result: 3.3529011872561614
correct result 3: 5.836344458981557, actual result: 5.836344458981557
correct result 2: 2.9950208717729656, actual result: 2.9950208717729656
correct result 1: 5.144743159869513, actual result: 5.144743159869513
```

If you are satisfied with getting back results in task-submission rather than task-completion order, then use method `imap` and there is no need to pass back and forth array indices:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np

def compute_sum(array):
    s = 0
    for a in array:
        s += a
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_list = [np.random.random(10) for _ in range(5)]
    n = len(array_list)
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), n)
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    for i, s in enumerate(pool.imap(compute_sum, array_list)):
        print(f'correct result {i}: {array_list[i].sum()}, actual result: {s}')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
correct result 0: 4.841913985702773, actual result: 4.841913985702773
correct result 1: 4.836923014762733, actual result: 4.836923014762733
correct result 2: 4.91242274200897, actual result: 4.91242274200897
correct result 3: 4.701913574838348, actual result: 4.701913574838349
correct result 4: 5.813666896917504, actual result: 5.813666896917503
```

**Update**

You can also use method `apply_async` specifying a callback function to be invoked when a result is returned from your worker function, `compute_sum`. `apply_async` returns a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` whose `get` method will block until the task has completed and returns the return value from the completed task. But here, since, we are using a callback function that will automatically be called with the result when the task completes instead of calling method `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get`, there is no need to save the `AsyncResult` instances. We also rely on calling methods `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.close()` followed by `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join()` to block until all submitted tasks have completed and results returned:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def compute_sum(i, array):
    s = 0
    for a in array:
        s += a
    return i, s

def calculation_display(result, t):
    # Unpack returned tuple:
    i, s = t
    print(f'correct result {i}: {array_list[i].sum()}, actual result: {s}')
    result[i] = s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global array_list

    array_list = [np.random.random(10) for _ in range(5)]
    n = len(array_list)
    result = [0] * n
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), n)
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    # Get result as soon as it has been returned.
    # Pass to our callback as the first argument the results list.
    # The return value will now be the second argument:
    my_callback = partial(calculation_display, result)
    for i, array in enumerate(array_list):
        pool.apply_async(compute_sum, args=(i, array), callback=my_callback)
    # Wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('results:', result)
```

Prints:

```None
correct result 0: 5.381579338696546, actual result: 5.381579338696546
correct result 1: 3.8780497856741274, actual result: 3.8780497856741274
correct result 2: 4.548733927791488, actual result: 4.548733927791488
correct result 3: 5.048921365623381, actual result: 5.048921365623381
correct result 4: 4.852415747983676, actual result: 4.852415747983676
results: [5.381579338696546, 3.8780497856741274, 4.548733927791488, 5.048921365623381, 4.852415747983676]
```

Comment: My purpose is that let sub-process inform main-process that the calculation is finished, so that the GUI in main-process could show something. For example, I have a function `calculation_display()`. I want `calculation_display` is called when every sub-process finish the calculation. Is it possible for `pool.imap`?

Comment: See the **Update** appended to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. Is it possible to pass some parameters to `calculation_display()`? For example, there is a array `result = [0]*5`, and I want to pass `result` to `calculation_display`. In the `calculation_display`, I want `result[i] = s`. Is it possible?

Comment: The "trick" is to use `functools.partial`. See the update to the update.